# How to show categories in the left column in magento?

Tags: magento2, category, sidebar, sub-categories

[image: how to show categories here]

Like u see in above picture i want it to show my categories and subcategories also i want this column  to work on products to not just in the home page

Thanks

Resolved using "Sebwite" extension.

Comment: can somebody help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below extension and modify as per your Vendor_Module.

> Link - https://github.com/magento1994/SidebarCategory

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for the module can you tell me where I have to clone this git ? and add it to magento thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can download zip from the same link

Comment: can you please be a little more specific with linux commands i pretty new to magento thanks

Comment: git clone https://github.com/magento1994/SidebarCategory.git

Comment: Or you can download the zip and put it in magentoroot/app/code

Comment: First learn how to install extension in magento 2 , magento directory structure , extension directory structure

Comment: After that you understand how to do

Comment: And in simple word , clone my code in different directory outside ur magento installation then copy Biren folder inside magentoroot/app/code

Comment: Will discuss tomorrow morning

Comment: Also for hint ur directory structure is wrong inside app/code

Comment: Done or not...??

Comment: can you plz tell me your magento directory path plz

Comment: ok now inside app code my module directory structure should be /var/www/magento/app/code/Biren/SideCat

Comment: i think you are using some other extension not the same which is given in answer so plz ask to the extension provider

Comment: ok so in last word as i told you my extension should be inside /var/www/magentoapp/code/Biren/SideCat/

Comment: ok so send me registration.php file path plz

Comment: inside my extension 1 registartion.php file is there app/code/Biren/SideCat/registration.php

Comment: like this, so can you plz send me the path

Comment: i said path not code...

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/wpqxmkh  see this and this is my last reply on this question ...

Comment: also my extension is for category page and you are checking in home page

Comment: add 1 more layout if you want in home page layout file name cms_index_index.xml

Comment: catalog_product_view.xml layout

Comment: as a friend 1 suggestion for you , plz learn layout structure for  different pages...